# WFS Stored Query is not stored correctly - it is stored with null in tag

Tags: geoserver, wms

If I want to list stored queries I get this error:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 735; The element type "null:ValueReference" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</null:ValueReference>"
```

I found out, why this error occurs.

I created the `Stored Query` with this XML

```
<wfs:CreateStoredQuery service="WFS" version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.org/fes/2.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <wfs:StoredQueryDefinition id="test">
        <wfs:Parameter name="gemarkungsname" type="xsd:string"/>
        <wfs:QueryExpressionText returnFeatureTypes="KRE_ALKIS:sg_flurstueck_f" language="urn:ogc:def:queryLanguage:OGC-WFS::WFS_QueryExpression" isPrivate="false">
            <wfs:Query typeNames="KRE_ALKIS:sg_flurstueck_f">
                <fes:Filter>
                    <fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>


    <fes:ValueReference>gemarkungsname</fes:ValueReference>${gemarkungsname}</fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    </fes:Filter>
                </wfs:Query>
            </wfs:QueryExpressionText>
        </wfs:StoredQueryDefinition>
    </wfs:CreateStoredQuery>
```

But on the server in the data directory was this XLS stored. Here you can see `<null:Filter` instead of `<fes:Filter`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wfs:StoredQueryDescription xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="test">
    <wfs:Parameter name="gemarkungsname" type="xs:string"/>
    <wfs:QueryExpressionText isPrivate="false" language="urn:ogc:def:queryLanguage:OGC-WFS::WFS_QueryExpression" returnFeatureTypes="KRE_ALKIS:sg_flurstueck_f">
        <wfs:Query wfs:typeNames="KRE_ALKIS:sg_flurstueck_f">
            <null:Filter xmlns:null="http://www.opengis.org/fes/2.0">
                <null:PropertyIsEqualTo>${gemarkungsname}<null:ValueReference>gemarkungsname</fes:ValueReference>
                </fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            </fes:Filter>
        </wfs:Query>
    </wfs:QueryExpressionText>
</wfs:StoredQueryDescription>
```

Can someone explain to me, why the `null` is saved instead of `fes` in my `Stored Query` in the data directory? I can edit the XML file. I can change here `null` to `fes` and everything works fine. But I like to understand why my Ajax not work correctly.